# how to give batch of documents to lucene?

Tags: indexing, lucene

I have lots of ".txt" files in a single directory and I wants to give it to *lucene* for indexing.
I read all files of directory and for each file make its document and then use *indexwriter.addDocument(Document)* to give these files to lucene.
Is it possible to make all documents and give all of them to lucene?? I mean does lucene support this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was added in [lucene 3.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3112)

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to add each document on its own.

Furthermore I recommend using a configurable batch size to load just as many txt files and index them and carry on as long as there are more text files. This way you will not run into memory problems when you have bigger files.